# How to install "libgtk1.2" on Ubuntu 12.04/64bit?

Tags: 12.04, updates

Is there any way to install "libgtk1.2" on Ubuntu 12.04, please? 
I try to install that in terminal :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:adamkoczur/gtk1.2
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libgtk1.2
```

Output :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libgtk1.2
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libgtk1.2'
```

any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libgtk1.2` is no longer supported in 12.04.

You need to install `libgtk2.0` and the packages are available in repository. To install libgtk2.0 use the command

```
 sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0
```

For dependencies and other information look [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libgtk2.0-0)

Hope this helps.